# In React ES6, is there any benefit to using an imported component that contains only one element tag with a class?

Tags: performance, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my application, I have many instances of:

```
<div className="node">
    // various types of other elements
</div>
```

Is there any benefit, such as better performance, to creating a component that contains this markup and importing and using it rather than just writing the markup itself in other components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the performance of putting it in a separate component to be a bit worse, due to an extra `render` call. I'd also expect the difference to be unnoticeable. There's also [some overhead](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2873) to additional modules, at least in Webpack.

The biggest advantage is the advantage that you get any time you pull common code into a function or class:

- You give a name to the functionality, to make your code more self-documenting.
- You reduce duplication in your code and introduce a single place to make future changes. This is minor now, because the only duplication is the `node` className, but you may find that you need to make changes in the future, and having a separate component then could help.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well and I do recall seeing that link (or a similar one) regarding the overhead in Webpack and Browserify. At most, later, I may add in the ability to pass in additional classes and maybe even an ID but for the most part it would be just `<Node>{children}</Node>`. Again, I ask my original question because in many examples and tutorials I have seen things such as `<Section><Container><Form></Form></Container></Section>` with not much actual JSX markup anywhere and I can't imagine that these contain many elements themselves.

Comment: @spunge - Thinking about it a bit more, I guess I might make the decision based on what my intended semantics are. If I'm doing semantic HTML, I'd find it clearer to just do HTML tags. If there's any change I'd want to add React behaviors or use React to manage styling, I'd start thinking about using components instead.

Comment: Again, I am agreeing with you about this. For my specific example, the element would only be used for it's class for spacing between multiple adjacent instances of the same element such as `.node + .node { padding-top: 30px; }`.

Answer (score 0):

since you aren't actually doing any class related things in the repeated markup, you could just do

```
const Node = (
    <div className="node" >
        // various other elements
    </div>
 );
```

and then use `<Node/>` wherever you need it.
This should be the most efficient.